# Is there a problem with this service neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've been having issues with lights flickering and unbalanced voltage on either leg and after some research it seems like it's a bad neutral somewhere. These are the service wires coming into the electrical panel. Could the browning(not sure if that's oxidation) affect the connection or would it be something farther down the line on the power companies side?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your picture for sure if that's okay, but usually lost neutrals happen at the pole -- that's where it's flapping around in the breeze, and it's much more likely to break up there.  If you call your utility and tell them you have a lost neutral, they'll send someone out to check.  IMO it's worth doing that before messing with this box any further.

Comment: While I agree with @NateS, I would also note that I can't see any "goop" (noalox) compound on the wires to prevent oxidation. In the pic everything looks new enough that it probably isn't causing your problem, but you should double check to see if the original installer applied the Noalox compound.   If not it needs to be done and the only way to do it is to have the POCO pull the meter.

Comment: Te emphasize what @NateS.states, have this fixed *as soon as possible*. As you probably know, having done careful analysis, a bad neutral can damage appliances and cause fires.

Comment: Are these the service cables coming into your METER? Or into your PANEL? Usually uou can't see the ones coming into your meter, because the meter is sealed and you have to remove it to open the can to see the utility cables. These look fine, but that doesn't mean the utility connection is...

Answer (score 3):

This is not a time to plod along with exhaustive diagnostics and cautious bug-hunting.  This is a time for swift action.

The fact that you are seeing low voltage on one leg and high voltage on the other is evidence enough.

## Call the power company and report an outage

Because 95% chance the problem is on the part of the service drop that they own.